# Twilio Flow - Auto Arrange

Tags: twilio, twilio-flow

I am trying to import the json to the Twilio flow.  But the widgets are overlapped/distorted and readability is lost.  Can you suggest a way to do this from Twilio (Say, auto arrange).  I checked the blogs, but it shows nothing to use like auto-arrange.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Tried to arrange the widgets in the Twilio flow while importing from json.  I expect the feature (auto-arrange) or any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree this would be a helpful feature. I'm afraid this is currently not possible.

I'll forward your feedback to the engineering team, though.